# get data from service to component subscribe method

Tags: angular, firebase

Dear I'm new to angular and try to understand. At the moment i have some lists in Firebase what i need in my component. I recieve them in the service file.

Service:

```
businessRef: AngularFireList<any>;
  business$: Observable<any[]>;
businessData: any[];

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase,private router: Router) {  
}  
  getAllData(){

   this.businessRef = this.db.list('/types/business');
   this.business$ = this.businessRef.valueChanges();  
    this.business$.subscribe(businessData=> {
      this.businessData = businessData;
      console.log(this.businessData);
    });
  }
```

Component:

```
 constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase, public questionSerivce: QuestionService) {

   }

   this.businessDateGraph = this.questionSerivce.getAllData();
   console.log(this.businessDateGraph);
```

The console log of the service gives me the right output but when i try to access that values in the component I recieved the error 'undifined'.

Is there anyone who can help me further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your subscription cannot be in service, you need to subscribe your observable into your component.

If you make subscription in service, your method returns to your component without waiting subscription results.

In order to fix this issue, In Service:

```
getAllData(){
   this.businessRef = this.db.list('/types/business');
   this.business$ = this.businessRef.valueChanges();  
   return this.business$;
}
```

In your component:

```
public allData :any[];

getAllData()
{
    this.questionSerivce.getAllData().subscribe(res => this.allData = res);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you help! I need the data when the page is loaded to fill a chart. But when I call the function this.getAllData(); in de ngOnInit in the component i either recieve an error message 'undefined', do you have any idea how to fix this? BTW Thanks for you time and help!

Code in NgOnInit

this.businessDateGraph = this.getAllData();
    console.log(this.businessDateGraph);

Comment: you need to put ngIf="allData" to your html component. So that when the data is unavailable it is not loaded. Even if you use ngOnInit this does not mean that allData is going to be available when the page is loaded